# On Which type of Requirement we use AWS SDK instead of using AWS Console?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new in AWS. I also explore AWS Java SDK, & create some basic programs. My question is all services provided by SDK is already doing on AWS Console. Where we use AWS SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

To run a Java on AWS (e.g. in an EC2 instance), you wouldn't necessarily need to use the SDK.  However, if you want to access or manage AWS resources within your program, then you'd use the SDK.

For example, some common uses are storing your data in S3 or DynamoDB.  Additionally, you can use the SDK to script the creation of your entire application stack.